# Need help displaying children lists without spacing the parent lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am printing out a list of college majors we offer, then within each major, we have concentrations for each major.

Our Science Major has the following concentrations: Environmental Science & Forestry, Chiropractic, Chemistry, Biology

Here is a screen shot of what it is doing:
[image]

I do not want the spacing it displays (I do not want the spacing you see after Human Resource Management AAS and after Psychology.) in the screen shot, any help is appreciated.

The source would look like this:

```css
.col-middle .majors-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.col-middle ul.majors-list {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.col-middle ul.concentrations-list {
  overflow: auto;
}

.col-middle .concentrations-list li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="majors-list">
  <li>Major
    <ul class="concentrations-list">
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Major
    <ul class="concentrations-list">
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Major
    <ul class="concentrations-list">
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Major
    <ul class="concentrations-list">
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
      <li>Concentration Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean the line break between '&' and 'Forestry'?

Comment: We need more specific info if you want any help.  What spacing don't you want?  What should it look like?  Hard to help without any info.

Comment: I think it has to do with the space under the first major on the left column.  But I dont see how it got into columns in the first place.  Looks like tables to me!

Comment: I do not want the spacing you see after Human Resource Management AAS and after Psychology.

Comment: why don't you break the list into to ul with float:left; width:50%

Comment: @Kostis, that ruins the fun!  The point is to have clean HTML and still have a nice representation.  Having two lists doesn't make sense, really, because you're crossing the lines between representation and meaning.

Comment: This list is dynamically generated.

Comment: How did it get in two columns?  That seems to be causing the problem, and there's no mention of columns in your code.

Comment: @Karl, the top li's have a width of 50% and are floated left.  This is how they come into columns.

Comment: DocType: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

Comment: @Brad, Can Javascript be used to split the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some javascript you won't be able to do this. With mozilla or webkit you can use -[moz|webkit]-column-count: 2; but even that isn't going to give you the same solution that the given css is almost providing for you, in other words the ordering will be vertical instead of horizontal. When I was playing with the column-count property, the inner lists were being split on the columns too, which I assume would not be adequate either.

A javascript solution, which I believe could be accomplished pretty easily with a framework like jquery, would probably take each of the li elements and dynamically position them with a combination of position:relative and position:absolute attributes and a little bit of math.

Answer (score 0):

Try float: right instead of float: left.

This works for Firefox 2.  Doesn't work with (many) other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give the concentrations-list class a `display: none;` property in CSS. 
You can then display one of the sublists by giving it onclick event that changes the class to concentrations-list-showing and adding a concentrations-list-showing class to the CSS and giving it a `display: block;` property.

Comment: The concentrations list (sub list) needs to display at all times, so students can see what the college offers.

Comment: i see, I thought you wanted to make it a "menu" where user clicks on the department and it unrolls into a major list

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS3 Columns but I'm guessing you need this to work in *that* browser.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is making your ul.majors-list display: inline; (or inline-block) and float: left; It *may* work.

---

The above should have been "try making your **ul.majors-list li** display: inline;". But I can't get it to work just playing around with it quick. Not sure how you're going to be able to do this without getting rid of the top-most ul and just making each be their own list.